# Set multiple Post Terms in same Taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy, terms, query-posts

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out this problem. I have looked at various StackExchange threads but nothing seems to work.

Long story short. I have a custom table that updates every day which stores data about the Daily, Weekly, and Monthly popularity of post products.

Here is an extract of the table:

| id | date | rank_d | rank_w | rank_m |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-09-14 | sku-1 |  |  |
| 2 | 2021-09-14 | sku-2 |  |  |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |
| 17 | 2021-09-01 | sku-2 | sku-27 | sku-3 |
| 18 | 2021-09-01 | sku-11 | sku-1 | sku-4 |

*rank_d*, *rank_w*, *rank_m* represent the SKU of the product.
While daily ranking is filtered by "today" date the monthly/weekly popular product is stored at the end of the table (i.e. at rows 17/18).

I need to update post terms for each post product associated with the SKU in the table in order to filter it within the front end. I can add 1 term but I need support to add more terms to the same SKU. In particular, at 2021-09-14, I expect this outcome:

- sku-1 = Daily;Weekly --> (**I can't add multiple terms**)
- sku-2 = Dayly
- sku-3 = Monthly
- sku-4 = Monthly
- sku-11 = /
- sku-27 = Weekly

Here below the code:

```
add_action('init', 'update_post_terms_gtrends_w_m');

function update_post_terms_gtrends_w_m() {
    global $wpdb;
    
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'suppress_filters' => true,
        'meta_key' => '_sku'
    );
    
    $today = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( '-1 days' )); 

    $posts_array = get_posts( $args );
    
    $customTable_2 = $wpdb->prefix.'gtrends_top_w_m';
    
    foreach($posts_array as $post) {      
        $post_id = $post->ID;
        $post_sku = get_post_meta($post_id,'_sku',true);

// Get results from custom tables   
        $result_top_d = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT rank_d FROM $customTable_2  WHERE rank_d = '$post_sku'  and date = '$today' ");        
        $result_top_w = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT rank_w FROM $customTable_2  WHERE rank_w = '$post_sku' ");  
        $result_top_m = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT rank_m FROM $customTable_2  WHERE rank_m = '$post_sku' ");
            
// Assign post-terms                    
        if ($result_top_d != NULL){
            wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, array(2119), 'popular', true );            
            }
        
        else if ($result_top_w != NULL ){
            wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, array(2120), 'popular', true );            
            }
        
        else if ($result_top_m != NULL ){
            wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, array(2118), 'popular', true );            
            }
    
        else{
            wp_remove_object_terms($post_id, array(2118,2119,2120), 'popular' );
        }               
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance